# Horror movie where a girl gives a boy a necklace for protection against an entity that ends up killing his mother

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I was seven or eight and I believe it was in 2011. It was on the Syfy channel. I believe there was a sequel as well. All I remember is the scene from the beginning.

A young girl goes into a boys house and gives him a necklace to protect him from a creature or spirit. The entity kills his mother and he hides in the bathtub with all the lights on.

The same entity haunts the little girl as she gets older and attacks her son.

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Darkness Falls](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0282209/)*** (2003)...?

> A vengeful spirit has taken the form of the Tooth Fairy to exact vengeance on the town that lynched her 150 years earlier. Her only opposition is the only child, now grown up, who has survived her before.

I don't believe there's any special necklace in this film, but it's very similar to your description aside from that.

The story is set in a town called Darkness Falls, which is haunted by a vengeful spirit nicknamed the Tooth Fairy. It visits children on the night that they lose their last baby tooth and kills anyone who sees its face, but has a strong aversion to light, much like a vampire.

The film starts with a nighttime prologue showing the young protagonist, Kyle, standing in front of a bathroom mirror, removing his last baby tooth. His mother subsequently tucks him into bed, and a few minutes later, his best friend, Caitlin, climbs in through his bedroom window to pay him a short visit. No necklace is involved in this scene.

After Caitlin leaves, the Tooth Fairy comes for Kyle and he cries out when he catches a glimpse of its face with his flashlight. His mother comes out of her bedroom to investigate and finds him hiding in the bathroom with the light turned on, terrified. He warns her to stay in the light, but she doesn't believe him and is killed by the Tooth Fairy. Kyle sees this and runs back into the bathroom, cowering in the bathtub.

We then skip forward 12 years, and Caitlin's younger brother is now suffering from night terrors. She phones Kyle, whom she hasn't seen since the night of his mother's death, to ask him how he got over the night terrors he experienced after that, but he explains that he never did. The rest of the film involves them trying to find a way to protect Caitlin's brother, and themselves, from the Tooth Fairy.

You can view the scene where Caitlin visits Kyle in his bedroom at around the 2:05 mark in the video clip below. You can view the scene where Kyle's mother is killed at around the 7:34 mark.

Comment: The town name cracks me up.  If I moved to somewhere named Darkness Falls, I'd feel ripped off if it _wasn't_ cursed.

Comment: This answer unlocked a memory of being explained the plot of this movie at a childhood sleepover. It doesn't sound much scarier now that I'm an adult!